# Error configuring a sql package with functions and procedures

Tags: sql, oracle-apex-5.1

I am new to SQL, and I am attempting to create a package with functions and procedures unfortunately I have encountered issue and the following error has occurred

> 'PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FUNCTION" when expecting one of the following: is authid as compress compiled wrapped accessible The symbol "is" was substituted for "FUNCTION" to continue. Compilation failed, line 2 (17:11:44) PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NUMBER" when expecting one of the following: ( Compilation failed, line 3 (17:11:44) PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following: is as compress compiled wrapped'

I have read it and done research to try fix the issue but have have not been able to fix it could i possibly have some assistance to direct me to fixing the issue. 
thanks stack overflow for reviewing the question as I am a newbie to SQL.

Package specification

```js
create or replace package e_con_pack
FUNCTION GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)RETURN l_con_id;
procedure ADD_CONSULTANT;
procedure update_location;
procedure delete_con;
end e_con_pack;
```

package body

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY e_con_pack

    create or replace FUNCTION 
    GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS  
     LOCATION VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
      SELECT LOCATION INTO LOCATION FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = p_con_id;    
      SELECT CST_NAME INTO p_con_name FROM LDS_CONSULTANT WHERE CONSULTANT_ID = p_con_id;

    RETURN l_con_id;
    END;

    create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_CONSULTANT
    ( p_con_id           LDS_CONSULTANT.CONSULTANT_ID%type,
      p_con_name         LDS_CONSULTANT.CST_NAME%type,
      p_con_start        LDS_CONSULTANT.START_DATE%type,
      p_con_end          LDS_CONSULTANT.LEAVE_DATE%type,
      p_con_loc          LDS_CONSULTANT.LOCATION%type,
      p_con_spec         LDS_CONSULTANT.SPECIALIST_AREA%type)
    IS
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO LDS_CONSULTANT (CONSULTANT_ID, CST_NAME, START_DATE, LEAVE_DATE, LOCATION, SPECIALIST_AREA)
    VALUES (p_con_id, p_con_name, p_con_start, p_con_end, p_con_loc, p_con_spec);
    END;

    create or replace PROCEDURE update_location (
      p_con_id     IN lds_consultant.consultant_id%type,
      p_con_loc   IN lds_consultant.location%type
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
      UPDATE lds_consultant
        SET
          location = p_con_loc
      WHERE consultant_id = p_con_id;
    END;

    create or replace PROCEDURE delete_con (
      p_con_id  IN lds_consultant.consultant_id%type )
        As
        Begin   

             Delete from LDS_CONSULTANT Where CONSULTANT_ID=p_con_id;

    END;
    END e_con_pack;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in the return type in the package difination

> FUNCTION GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out
>   VARCHAR2)RETURN **l_con_id**;

should be something else like

```
FUNCTION GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)RETURN NUMBER;
```

also inside the function body there is no difination to the variable l_cod_id that you return

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the keyword **`AS/IS`**. Try the following:

```
create or replace package e_con_pack
AS
    FUNCTION GET_LOCATION_namel (p_con_id in NUMBER, p_con_name out VARCHAR2)
:
:
```